# Python str.contains from two or more dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, pandas

I want to check if a string contains one or more values from two dictionaries.

```
company = {"AXP": "American Express", "BIDU": "Baidu"}
stock_index = {"GOOG": "Google"}

for c, i in zip(company, stock_index):
    df.loc[df.name.str.contains(c, i), "instrumentclass"] = "Equity"
```

For some reason, it only writes `"Equity"` for the first match in the dictionaries, i.e. `"AXP":"American Express"`. For `"Baidu"`and `"Google"`, nothing happens.

I know that I can combine the dictionaries to one as seen below, but I would prefer not to.

```
benchmarks = company.copy()
benchmarks.update(stock_index)
```

---

The data is written and retrieved with help of a `pandas DataFrame`.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG AXP", "SHORT AXP", "LONG BIDU", "LONG GOOG"], columns=["name"])
```

The code copies the column `name` to column `instrumentclass` and by doing this is supposed to substitute each cell to `"Equity"` if it contains `"AXP"`, `"BIDU"` or `"GOOG"`.

Comment: What's `df`? Please write a minimum working example.

Comment: df is a Pandas DataFrame. I'll update the question shortly with a working example.

Comment: From the documentation for `zip():` *The returned list is truncated in length to the length of the shortest argument sequence*

Comment: @boardrider Ah, so that's why it doesn't work. Is there a solution to make it  check through two dictionaries without combining them?

Comment: Loop over all your dictionaries, and check for value existence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you start by breaking down this data, like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(["LONG AXP", "SHORT AXP", "LONG BIDU", "LONG GOOG"],
                  columns=["name"])

# split on spaces and get the last part
df["company_name"] = df.name.str.split().str.get(-1)

>>> print df
        name company_name
0   LONG AXP          AXP
1  SHORT AXP          AXP
2  LONG BIDU         BIDU
3  LONG GOOG         GOOG
```

Now, it's much easier to work with these strings. Given this is a sample of your dictionaries:

```
company = {"AXP": "American Express", "BIDU": "Baidu"}
stock_index = {"GOOG": "Google"}
```

You can exploit "dictonary views" which behave like sets in Python:

```
# this is Python 2, if you use Python 3, .keys() method returns a view
all_companies = company.viewkeys() | stock_index.viewkeys()

>>> print all_companies
{'AXP', 'BIDU', 'GOOG'}
```

So now, we have a set-like object we can use to filter on the data and set "Equity":

```
df.loc[df.company_name.isin(all_companies), "instrumentclass"] = "Equity"
```

If you are concerned about not joining these dictionaries like that, you might want to consider using something like a ChainMap: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.ChainMap
 That's Python 3 standard library, but backports to Python 2 should exist.

Comment: Thanks, just a follow up: If I have more than two words in `name`, how can I split it and use the last two words together? For `LONG AXP VOX`, something like `str.get(-2:)`?